# Store user Role into one table field or separate table with roles

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I want to ask you what is the best flexible way to store user Roles. My idea is to use one table field to store the user ROLE:

https://github.com/rcbandit111/wiki/blob/master/src/main/java/org/engine/production/entity/Users.java#L53

Into the original code that I sue for example there is a separate table to store the user's role:

https://github.com/murraco/spring-boot-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/murraco/model/Role.java

This means that I need to do additional SQL query with JOIN in order to get the user role. From your experience which approach is better - one table for the role and user or 2 tables with JOIN(and 2 SQL insert queries)?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have one role per user, one role field in User entity/table is not a bad idea at all, go for it.

But, if one User can have multiple roles and you have several hundreds of users, then you must use a separate table for roles and then map them (say many-to-many relationship).

For a full blown example, using multiple roles for multiple users, take a look at [this example](https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks).